# How to do manual sort with input number

Tags: python

```py
num1 = input("enter number 1:")
num2 = input("enter number 2:")
num3 = input("enter number 3.")
small = 0
mid = 0
larg = 0

if num1 < num3 and num1 < num2:
    small = num1
    if num2 < num3 and num2 < num1:
        small = num2
    else:
        small = num3

elif num1 < num2 and num1 < num3:
    mid = num1
    if num2 > num1 and num2 < num3:
        mid = num2
    else:
        mid = num3

elif num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:
    larg = num1
    if num2 > num1 and num2 > num3:
        larg = num2
    else:
        larg = num3

print(small,mid,larg)
```

When I run and input numbers `100` `200` & `300`, console shows `300` `0` `0`.

Comment: Post the code, do not post images of the code

Comment: Unless you are on python 2.x, `input()` returns a string - and you compare strings. please [edit] your questions and format your code. You need to convert strings tro numbers - google it. Your comparisonst do not match: if num1 is smaller then num3 and num2 then num2 cannot be smaller num1: `if num1 < num3 and num1 < num2: ... if num2 < num3 and num2 < num1:`. Your logic is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method:

```
num1 = int(input('Enter num 1: '))
num2 = int(input('Enter num 2: '))
num3 = int(input('Enter num 3: '))

small, mid, large = sorted([num1, num2, num3])
print(small, mid, large)
```

## More manual method

```
def smallest(x, y, z):
  if x < y and x < z:
    return x
  elif y < x and y < z:
    return y
  else:
    return z

def largest(x, y, z):
  if x > y and x > z:
    return x
  elif y > x and y > z:
    return y
  else:
    return z

def middle(x, y, z):
    if x < y:
        if y < z:
            return y
        elif x < z:
            return z
        else:
            return x
    else:
        if x < z:
            return x
        elif y > z:
            return y
        else:
            return z

small = smallest(num1, num2, num3)
large = largest(num1, num2, num3)
mid = middle(num1, num2, num3)

print(small, mid, large)
```

Other Methods: [How to manually sort a list of numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967020/how-to-manually-sort-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Comment: _How to do manual sort with input number_ - thats not very manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = input("enter number 1:")
num2 = input("enter number 2:")
num3 = input("enter number 3.")
small = 0
mid = 0
larg = 0

if num1 < num3 and num1 < num2:
    small = num1
    if num2 < num3 and num2 < num1:
        small = num2
    else:
        small = num3

elif num1 < num2 and num1 < num3:
    mid = num1
    if num2 > num1 and num2 < num3:
        mid = num2
    else:
        mid = num3

elif num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:
    larg = num1
    if num2 > num1 and num2 > num3:
        larg = num2
    else:
        larg = num3
print(small,mid,larg)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input("enter number 1:"))
num2 = int(input("enter number 2:"))
num3 = int(input("enter number 3."))
small = 0
mid = 0
larg = 0

if num1 < num3 and num1 < num2:
    small = num1
elif num2 < num3 and num2 < num1:
    small = num2
else:
    small = num3

if num1 < num3 and num1 > num2:
    mid = num1
elif num2 < num1 and num2 > num3:
    mid = num2
else:
    mid = num3

if num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:
    larg = num1
elif num2 > num1 and num2 > num3:
    larg = num2
else:
    larg = num3
print(small,mid,larg)
```

There were issues in conditions I have corrected it hopefully it will work.